# Google Sheet unique values and adjacent data

Tags: google-sheets

so we got this google sheet (yes i already posted this on google forums, just expanding options) where we keep track of product orders, so the sheet contains names, and products, the thing is because of other parameters we structured the sheet so each item a client gets, is added on a new line, what we are trying to figure out, is how we can show this data, condensed so we don't see the repeated names, so we then export that data to create receipts, attached is a link to a demo sheet:

LINK TO DEMO  >>  [THE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1boZaGA0oaD4y7RABG2FYLoAQ_xDw-7HqEGhOAAT1BLs/edit?usp=sharing):

```
          WHAT WE HAVE:     >>>    WHAT WE WOULD LIKE TO ACCOMPLISH:

       NAME    -  PRODUCT            NAME    -  PRODUCT
       DANIEL  -  ORANGE            DANIEL   -  ORANGE
       ALICE   -  PINEAPPLE         ALICE    -  PINEAPPLE - APPLE
       ALICE   -  APPLE             ROBERT   -  BANANA - KIWI 
       ROBERT  -  BANANA
       ROBERT  -  BANANA
       ROBERT  -  KIWI
```

Comment: `UNIQUE`,`TEXTJOIN`,`IF`

Answer (score 0):

There's a single formula solution, but it's simpler to split by 3 formulas:

[image]

- `A:B` - data range,
- `D1` - prepare the data. The formula is: `=SORT(UNIQUE(A:B))`. Need sort in case the order is not by NAME.
- `F1` - prepare chars for groups of NAMEs. The formula is: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OFFSET(D1,,,COUNTA(D:D))=OFFSET(D1,1,,COUNTA(D:D))," - ",","))`
- `D1` - the final result: `={UNIQUE(FILTER(D:D,D:D<>"")),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",1,E:F),","))}`